# Retrieving contional value inside Inlude in entity framework

Tags: angular, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I have a `dotnet core 2.0` backend and `angular2+` frontend application.

I would like to get a list of participants where `event` field is equal to "baseline" (comes from dropdown menu in the HTML) in the schedules class. I have a `one-to-many` relationship between `Participant` and `Schedule` class.

`Participant.cs` class:

```
public class Participant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    // RelationShips
    public ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }

    public Participant()
    {
        Schedules = new Collection<Schedule>();
    }
}
```

And my `Schedule.cs` class:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public string AppointmentTime { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    // RelationShip
    public Participant Participant { get; set; }
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
}
```

I have an `angular 2+` frontend to use this to get the list of participants and their schedules where the event is equal to "baseline". The baseline is coming from the frontend. Basically, a hard-coded drop-down menu item.

I am able to get all schedules with all events as below:

```
return await context.Participants
            .Include(x => x.Schedules)
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this gives me again people with all schedules. I need people with all schedule where `event` is equal to "baseline".

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
return await context. Participants
            .Include(x => x.Schedules.Where(v => v.Event == "baseline"))
            .ToListAsync();
```

But this gives me nothing. 
What would be the way to accomplish this? I don't remember where I read but someone said entity framework doesn't support this yet. I am not sure this is true.. 
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is error stack I have:

> InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from Schedule v in x.Schedules where [v].Event.ToLower().Equals(__ToLower_0) select [v]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=74639

Comment: Did you try using `equals` instead of `==`?

Comment: Yep. `return await context.Participants
                .Include(x => x.Schedules.Where(v => v.Event.Equals("baseline")))
                .ToListAsync();` and doesn't work

Comment: can you try v => v.Event.ToLower().Equals("baseline".ToLower())?

Comment: have you tried to run the similar query in database? Is it giving records?

Comment: @viveknuna `Where` is not supported inside `Include`, the criteria doesn't matter.

Comment: @IvanStoev then gogo should use `join`. right?

Comment: I am unable to get any data from the database either. I have posted the error stack I have from the log.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bentity-framework-core%5D+or+%5Bef-core-2.0%5D+filtered+include This feature is one of the top requested, and still missing in EF.

Comment: Great! Then I am not alone. Do you think I can accomplish this using frontend? In my case, `angular`?

Comment: Check out [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)

Comment: EF doesn't support it, but with Linq2SQL you could accomplish it by (left outer) joining with context.Schedules.Where(v => v.Event == "baseline")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get a list of participants you could go the other way around, starting at `schedules` and getting the `Participant` references like this:

```
return context.Schedules.Where(s => s.Event == "baseline")
.Include(x => x.Participant).Select(x => x.Participant)
```

Comment: The current version of Entity framework doesn't support this as indicated in the comments. But this approach will do the work for me.